# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127 with ChromeDriver and Selenium in Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

This is the error I'm receiving when I'm executing my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 98, in start
>       self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 111, in assert_process_still_running
>       % (self.path, return_code) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
>   chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

Comment: which version of chrome browser and driver are you using ?

Comment: Google Chrome 71.0.3578.80

Comment: and your chrome driver version ?

Comment: 71.0.3578.33/chromedriver_linux64

Comment: you need to install chrome driver from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads here which is compatible to your chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
Try removing arguments. It may be because of two different chrome drivers.
If still not working then refer [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)
Also, use python3 to compile.